# how to migrate from Cs3 to Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, cs3

Although I am using Flash CS3 for development, my project
  is virtually pure AS3; My .FLA file is nothing more than a movie
  of 640x480 , no classes, no controls or libraries and my Action
  window has a single line of code

```
  include 'myscript.as'
```

which is one big as3 file of about 10,000 lines....

The swf file generated is only around 18k in size, but a lot is happening
  within the app....

My question/problem is , how do I compile my 'myscript.as' with flex 
  instead of cs3? ( I want to make use of the newer as3 functions , and
  want to compile via the command line )

I should mention, I've noticed in a lot of AS3 code there is something like
  the following

```
    public class someapp extends sprite
    {
    ....
    }
```

I have no classes whatsoever in the code because everything runs inside
  my own state machine, will this be a problem with flex ? or can flex compile
  anything cs3 can compile ??

the swf (it's a video chat,airtime type app) is at 
  http://www.mebeam.net/chat_SO_demo

Comment: `I want to make use of the newer as3 functions`: do you mean it's currently written in AS2? And `I have no classes whatsoever in the code`: like only functions then?

Comment: the new as3 functions like p2p , echo cancel ,, which is not supported in cs3 ) or is it ??

Comment: yes, no classes,, just functions, and a finite state machine which is called apx 50 times per second

Comment: Those new functions are in fact in the new versions of the Flash Player. I suppose CS3 doesn't let you target anything higher than FP8 or so?

Answer (score 0):

First download a Flex SDK from http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Downloads/

Unzip it; in the unzipped folder, you'll find a directory called `bin`. In there are all the Flex compilers and tools. The one you'll need to compile Flex or ActionScript application is called `mxmlc`.

You will have to provide it with at least these three pieces of information:

- the root path of all your ActionScript source files
- the path of the file you want as an output file: this should of course have a .swf extension
- the path to the main ActionScript class; the entrypoint of your application

Now you can compile your application on the command line like this:

```
mxmlc -source-path+=/path/to/myproject/src -output=/path/to/myApp.swf /path/to/myproject/src/Main.as
```

As far as I know this entrypoint (the Main.as file in the example) must be a class, though I must admit I never tested it otherwise. So you will have to create at least this one class that extends Sprite and initiate your functional program from there.

```
public class Main extends Sprite {
    public Main() {
        firstGlobalFunction();
    }
}
```